# открыть еще одну вкладку в терминале с помощью Bash и Python

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu, bash

запускаю код в python3:`os.system(""" gnome-terminal --tab --title="tab 2" --command="bash -c 'cd /etc; $SHELL'" """)`, он открывает терминал с одной вкладкой. Как сделать, чтобы еще одной командой открыть новую вкладку в уже открытом терминале

Comment: Вопрос не относится ни к Python, ни к Ubuntu, ни к bash. Показанная вами команда лично у меня открывает именно новую вкладку в уже открытом терминале, так что вопрос непонятен

Comment: Хотя в более новых версиях gnome-terminal и в самом деле нет опции `--tab`

Comment: Нужно в этом (уже открытом) терминале добавить еще одну вкладку, только не в этой же команде, а другой, например через 5 минут чтоб добавилась

Comment: [можно другим путём](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2191093/4827341). вызов wmctrl — опционально.

Comment: хороший способ, но если я буду использовать графку в программе, то как с нее переключится на терминал и там создать вкладку. Код из примера берет активное окно, а нужно чтоб активным ставал терминал